# Multiple Odoo at same time

Tags: ubuntu, odoo-8, odoo-9, odoo-10

I want run to Odoo 8 and Odoo 9 simultaneously using different ports. I have tried changing ports in configuration file using xmlrpc-port but it shows an error "site can't be reached".

So may i get any solution on this please ?
Can you tell what should be the path of configuration file in Ubuntu.

Comment: ex:  --xmlrpc-port=7771

Comment: yes i have changed this port but it is not working